# Hard Fault when assinging value in 2D array, C

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, fault

Writing a C program in an ARM microcontroller, i get a hard fault when i try to assign a value in a 2D array, and i have absolutely no clue why this is happening

```
#include "GLCD.h"   
#include <LPC17xx.H> 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


const size_t w = 319;
const size_t h = 239;


int main (void) {

    bool  univ[h][w];
    int x,y;

    for (x = 0; x < w; x++) for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        univ[y][x] = 1;

    }
    while (1);
}
```

thanks

Comment: You really need some bracebrackets around your loops.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, if you look carefully, you'll see that his dimensions and indexes do indeed line up properly.

Comment: Depending on how your compiler is storing `bool`, that array will consume between ~75K and ~300K of stack space; is your stack big enough?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill oh, right, they do indeed. It's confusing how the outer induction variable is being used in the second position...

Comment: Why is your inner loop iterating over the rows and the outer loop over the columns? You'd get much better performance if you flip them.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill i too thought of this to be a memory problem, if that is indeed to problem, how would one go to avoid - circumvent that? thanks for your input

Comment: 1) 1 is not necessarily a valid boolean value. However, it should work. 2) suggest moving the univ[][] array off the stack, I.E. put it before main(). 3) pre-set the array, so as to eliminate that 'for' loop.  I.E. bool univ[w][h] = {{true}.{true};

Comment: It entirely depends on your toolchain and architecture, which we'd need to know more about. But one easy fix, if the problem actually is stack size, would be to move the array off the stack into global data space. Just move the declaration outside of main to the top level of the file and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Does it crash at first assignment or does it manage to do a couple of them and then crash?

Comment: Your suggestion of moving the declaration outside of main worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably causing a stack overflow. You request at least 76K of stack; embedded systems may have something more like 3K of available stack.

Consult the documentation for the operating system in use (or perhaps write some probing code and compare it with what's in your linker map etc. etc) to work out how much stack you actually do have available.

In the meantime, if you make this array `static` then you should get a link error if it is too big for the static data area. And you could save at least 7/8 of your space used by using bits instead of bools.

Comment: [Possibly relevant link](http://www.support.code-red-tech.com/CodeRedWiki/StackSize) if you're using the Code Red dev tools. If not then there should be similar documentation for whatever setup you are using.

Comment: The problem indeed was the stack size, by moving the declaration outside of the function it was solved, and now when i exceed the memory limit i get warned at compilation. Thanks!